# Will you require anything? vs. Do you need anything?

Tags: will-future

In a comic book I’m reading, a wife asks to her husband, who’s working late in his study, “Will you require anything?”

1. Why does she use “will” instead of “do”?
2. Is there any difference in a vibe between “require” and “need” in that situation?

Comment: It means "in the future", that is, anytime later tonight. Presumably she wants to know if it is all right for her to sleep, not if there is anything he needs now (assuming the antiquated role of a wife being his servant).

Comment: I got it why she said 'will' now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"Will" here implies "now, or going forward". "Require" is more formal in tone. Overall, "Will you require..." marks a master-servant relationship. It's something a butler might ask.

Comment: Yes, the background of the comic book is in late 1800 in England. Thank you for your comment!!